# Who is the partner who is "interested in my opinion"?

Tags: discussion, advertising, survey

I've just been presented with this:

[image]

Out of interest I clicked on it:

[image]

Now I don't really have any particular objection to this survey, per se. But I'm not sure I want to share information on my current role, etc with an unnamed "partner".

Why doesn't SO want to provide this information up front? Can we get some clarification on how this data will be used, etc?

Comment: My knowledge of this specific survey is limited, but I can tell you that in general if a partner doesn't want to brand a survey with their name or logo up front, it's because they don't want that information to affect your responses to their question(s). I can't speak to exactly how your data will be used, but because this campaign is run by both an advertiser _and_ Stack Overflow people working together, you can trust questions like yours were asked in advance of this campaign going live. I'll wait for others with more info to chime in, as they'll likely be more helpful.

Comment: i took the survey once,but even after taking the survey,i was shown again survey link when i logged in again after a duration of 5 hours,so retook it

Comment: @stevvve I hope your partner is accounting for selection bias because a lot of people (myself included) are probably going to be put off by answering questions for anonymous organisations.

Comment: @AntP where do I sign up?

Comment: But also, who's going to do this survey for a *negligible* chance of $250?

Comment: @immibis I suspect a sub (or super-)set of users who fill out the annual SO survey for no reward whatsoever.

Comment: Five bucks it's Microsoft

Comment: @TheGameiswar do you recall whether you were connecting from the same IP address both times you took the survey?  (I'm trying to figure out why SurveyMonkey let you re-take it.)

Comment: @KevinTroy ,yes , both times same ip

Comment: Curious, does this pop up for every user? Or it's based on reps/tags of users? I wonder if that information also get's transferred to the anonymous company...

Comment: @Jamiec When I fill out the annual dev survey, I know I'm going to see the results.  I'm not about to give my info to an unnamed "partner" for a chance to win a gift certificate.  In fact the chance to win part is insulting-  I'd be more likely to give it for free than for a misleading "chance".

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[Stevvve's right in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351624/who-is-the-partner-who-is-interested-in-my-opinion#comment487643_351624): the partner will remain anonymous because they want to make sure the results they're getting are as unbiased as possible. We do know who it is; we're not working with some shadowy agency that won't tell us who the client company is or anything like that. It's a technology company we have worked with before on display advertising.

I was told that "we'll be partnering with the company later in the year to disclose key findings from the survey to the community", so we have that to look forward to.

One thing I want to make clear is that the survey is administered by this partner company, not by Stack Overflow. Our Insights team has reviewed the questions for content, but each response goes directly to the partner, not to us. The current survey page does not make that clear at all, since it's just got a big Stack Overflow logo and nothing else. **That's a big oversight on our part**, and I apologize. I'll look at fixing it for this survey if we can, and we will definitely make sure it's clear on future surveys that get run like this (if any).

In the meantime, if filling out the survey for an anonymous company makes you uneasy, that's totally reasonable - just don't fill it out. No harm done there. We trust this particular company to treat your survey response data well, but it's ultimately your call whether that's enough for you to go on.

Comment: "we're not working with some shadowy agency that won't tell us who the client company is" But.... SO *is* the shadowy agency who won't tell us the client company in this case...! D= lol

Comment: Also point out what data is transferred to the partner beyond my response to the questions. f.i. any individual ids, email adress, name, ...

Comment: I mean there's a lot of trust here and the trust is very second hand. I have to trust you that your trust the company. I'm sure SO tries to do the right thing, but your idea of trust and my idea of trust may not coincide, so I think I'll leave this survey for now, thanks.

Comment: What does their privacy policy say? Oh, never mind -- it doesn't matter what it says if we don't even know who they are. Seems like SO is letting this anonymous partner use SO's good reputation to garner trust, and I think there's some harm in that.

Comment: @Caleb Not sure how they're garnering trust if we don't know who they are. And SO trusts this company enough to let that happen anyway, so what harm is there in that?

Comment: So... I'm not interesting enough to warrant such a survey myself ;), but between "It's a technology company we have worked with before on display advertising." and "we'll be partnering with the company later in the year to disclose key findings from the survey to the community" I'd feel pretty safe answering the questions.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier re: how interesting you are, the campaign is only running on a certain set of tags.

Comment: @SirRufo SurveyMonkey (the system the partner is using to collect responses) collects IP address as part of the survey collection.  Other than that, just the responses to the questions gets collected.  Stack Overflow isn't handing over any additional data that will get matched up with survey responses.

Comment: @KevinTroy I would expect that kind of information (including that it will be collected by the partner) on each survey.